# google.cloud storage python api create bucket in specified location

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I would like to create a bucket in the `EU` location in google cloud storage.  How do I set that?  [The docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-client.html) don't mention anything.

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Creates a bucket in the `US` location by default.

Answer (score 6):

```
bucket = Bucket(client, name='bucketname')
bucket.location = 'eu'
bucket.create()
```